# Disabling specific groups of rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm working with a large Rails application, and i've been tasked with disabling rake tasks that could be harmful if run on our production environments, such as db:migrate, reset, etc.  However i'm not sure what the best course of action here is.

So far my solution is to put a statement like this at the top of the databases.rake task

```
if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'development' || ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'test'
```

Now obviously this disables all the database rake tasks for all environments but development and test.  However, i feel like this is hacky and I dont like it.  Can anyone think of a better way to solve this problem, or does this solution pose any greater problems that I may not be realizing?

EDIT:  A side question to a problem i've encountered.  When i set my RAILS_ENV to 'production' via

```
export RAILS_ENV=production
```

That worked fine, however i need to set my environment back to the default ' ' environment.  When I try

```
export RAILS_ENV=
```

I get an error

```
No such file or directory - project_path/config/environments/.rb
```

Does anyone know how to reset the environment back to default?

Answer (score 1):

As for your side question, the default environment is "development". So you might try:

```
export RAILS_ENV=development
```

What you're doing is assigning an empty string to RAILS_ENV (which is different from it not existing at all, which is what you want). To accomplish this, try:

```
export -n RAILS_ENV
```

Also, if you find yourself switching environments like this for one-shot commands (like rake tasks and such), you might try NOT exporting the variable, just defining it when calling the command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

This way, after the command is completed, you don't have an exported RAILS_ENV variable; think of it as being defined just for that particular invocation of rake (or whichever command you wanted).

Answer (score 0):

http://kjvarga.blogspot.com/2009/12/rakefile-mods-prevent-destructive-rake.html looks promising.